# How to generate the right data structure for ngoptions in single request

Tags: angularjs, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to return a data structure for an Angular screen with several  dropdowns.

I don't want to make multiple requests to get the options for each select so I was hoping to create a single nested data structure in Django that contains all the options for each select (there are only a small number)

Angular wants something like this to use with the select and ngoptions directives:

```
{'booking_name': 'acme',
'current_sales_person': 2,
'sales_people_options': [
    {id: 1, name: 'rod'},
    {id: 2, name: 'jane'},
    {id: 3, name: 'freddy'}
],
... lots more fields here ...
```

}

sales_people_options would populate the options for the dropdown and current_sales_person indicates which salesperson is initially selected.

How can I get Django Rest Framework to return this in a single request from a ModelSerializer?

I could just create the JSON directly via JSONRenderer but I've got a lot of other fields so I'm keen to use ModelSerializer.

The only way seems to be to add a method called sales_people_options to my Model.

However - I've got several of these  fields to generate and it seems very wrong to add model methods for something that I only need for one specific serializer.

EDIT - I think I might need to subclass serializer.Field and override a method (probably field_to_native).

Answer (score 0):

This is just a json object. The Django rest framework is capable of returning json strings which you can then JSON.stringify the string returned to turn it into an object angular is expecting.

```
{'booking_name': 'acme',
'current_sales_person': 2,
'sales_people_options': [
    {id: 1, name: 'rod'},
    {id: 2, name: 'jane'},
    {id: 3, name: 'freddy'}
```

Checkout the Django JSON renderer; http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers

Comment: In this toy example that's correct - but I'm using a ModelSerializer because there's lots of other fields I need. So it's about how to get ModelSerializer to return this structure. I'll clarify in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a weird way to do it but it worked:

```
class BookingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class UserOptionsField(serializers.Field):
        def field_to_native(self, obj, field_name):
            return User.objects.all().values('id', 'username')

    sales_people_options = UserOptionsField()

    class Meta:
        model = Booking
        fields = (
            'id', 'booking_no', 'current_salesperson', 'sales_people_options',
        )
```

EDIT: And here's a generic solution:

```
class ModelOptionsField(serializers.Field):

    def __init__(self, source=None, label=None, help_text=None, queryset=None, fields=None):
        self.queryset = queryset
        self.fields = fields
        super(ModelOptionsField, self).__init__(source, label, help_text)

    def field_to_native(self, obj, field_name):
        return self.queryset.values(*self.fields)
```

that you use like this:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    my_options_list = ModelOptionsField(queryset=User.objects.all(), fields=('id', 'username'))
```

Comment: Im getting the following error implementing this code NotImplementedError at /api/v1/user/profiles/
ModelOptionsField.to_representation() must be implemented.
If you are upgrading from REST framework version 2 you might want `ReadOnlyField`.